# Change default validation error message (Regex validator)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, razor-2

I have a WebResources.resx file from where I'm successfully setting the default error messages for many validations like `FieldMustBeDate`, `FieldMustBeNumeric` among others.

Now I'm trying to change the default error message for RegularExpression validator, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation what is the key that I should use in the WebResources.resx file in order to replace the default error message.

I want to avoid using this ErrorMessageResourceName:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("SomeRegex", ErrorMessageResourceName="some_resource_name")]
public String documentNumber {get; set;}
```

I want my code to look like this (and still show MY default error message):

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("SomeRegex")]
public String documentNumber {get; set;}
```

Comment: You could derive from `RegularExpressionAttribute` and set a default `ErrorMessageResourceName` in there.

Comment: thank @Vache, I thought about that. But there should be a value that I can set in my WebResources.resx that can do that for me, something like 'FieldMustBeRegex' or something.....